# Differentiate between macros and keywords of the same name in lstlisting

Tags: listings

I'd like to display the following code fragment in a `lstlisting` environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \duck[stripes=text]
  \stripes{}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The syntax highlighting should be

- red for `tikzpicture`
- blue for commands `\begin \duck \stripes \end`
- orange for keyword `stripes`
- other elements like `text` should remain black (or should at least have another colour then the keywords)

I tried to misuse `emphstyle` to colour the keyword, but as there is a command of the same name `\stripes` also changes colour, while I only want `stripes` to be in orange and `\stripes` to remain blue.

This seems to be a known bug, from p. 31 of the listings documentation:

> Bug: `texcs`... interferes with other keyword lists. If, for example, `emph` contains the word `foo`, then the control sequence `\foo` will show up in `emphstyle`.

Is there any  other way to colour keywords or workaround?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{duckstyle}{%
    language={[latex]TeX},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    %
    keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={tikzpicture},
    %
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moretexcs={duck,stripes},
    %
    emphstyle=\color{orange!70!black},
    emph={stripes}
}

\lstset{style=duckstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}% <- Perfect color
  \duck[stripes=text]% <- Perfect color
  \stripes{}% <- \stripes should be blue :(
\end{tikzpicture}% <- Perfect color
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To make things even more complicated, my real use case is to show the code in a `tcblisting` which has the unfortunate side effect that the [perfect solution of Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389701/36296) fails to compile the output of the listing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}% needs version 0.4
% this will be available on ctan sometime in the next 24 hours
% currently: https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks.sty

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{duckstyle}{%
    language={[latex]TeX},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    %
    keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={tikzpicture},
    %
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moretexcs={duck,stripes},
    %
    moredelim=[is][\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{orange!70!black}]{|}{|},
}

\lstset{style=duckstyle}

\tcbset{listing options={style=duckstyle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={duck}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \duck[|stripes|]
  \stripes{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT2**

Getting closer: The `\pgfkeys{/duck/|stripes|/.style={stripes=#1}}` solution works for `\duck[|stripes|]`, but fails for `\duck[|stripes|={\stripes[color=blue]}]` with the error message

```
! Extra \fi.
\pgfkeyscurrentkey ->color\fi 
                              \ifduck@cape \begin {pgfinterruptboundingbox} ...
l.2     \duck[|stripes|={\stripes[color=blue]}]

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}% needs version 0.4
% this will be available on ctan sometime in the next 24 hours
% currently: https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks.sty

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{duckstyle}{%
    language={[latex]TeX},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    %
    keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={tikzpicture},
    %
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moretexcs={duck,stripes},
    %
    moredelim=[is][\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{orange!70!black}]{|}{|},
}

\lstset{style=duckstyle}

\tcbset{listing options={style=duckstyle}}

\pgfkeys{/duck/|stripes|/.style={stripes=#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={working}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \duck[|stripes|]
  \stripes{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={not working}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[|stripes|={\stripes[color=blue]}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see the Bug mention in the manual? Page 31, under directivestyle (right below texcsstyle)

Comment: perhaps you should try minted:-)

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I had not seen it before. I still hope for some workaround.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If there would only be some nice overview comparing the (dis)advantages ... (I never managed to get `minted` to work, probably too many different python installation cluttering my system)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a work-around you can use a delimiter to get orange keywords:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{duckstyle}{%
    language={[latex]TeX},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    %
    keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={tikzpicture},
    %
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moretexcs={duck,stripes},
    %
    moredelim=[is][\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{orange!70!black}]{|}{|},
}

\lstset{style=duckstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}% <- Perfect color
  \duck[|stripes|=text]% <- Perfect color
  \stripes{}% <- \stripes should be blue :(
\end{tikzpicture}% <- Perfect color
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

When using tcblisting (where the code is also executed) one must ensure that the key `|stripes|` is not unknown and does something senseful.

The easiest is to define alias-keys:

```
  \pgfkeys{/duck/|stripes|/.style={stripes={#1}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This solves exactly the problem I posted in my questions. However in my real document, I use `tcblisting` to show both the code and output and the `|` prevents the output from being compiled. Do you maybe know of any other delimiter I could try which would be ignored in the compilation of the result? (added a code example to the question) I know this was not part of the original question and if you don't have a solution for this new problem I will eventually accept your answer anyway (if no better answer comes around)

Comment: @samcarter: I added an edit.

Comment: Arrrg, I found yet another problem, sorry! Your solution works fine for `\duck[|stripes|]`, but as soon as I try to pass any argument, i.e. `\duck[|stripes|={\stripes[color=blue]}]` it fails -- for the error message, please see my second edit. But nevertheless, thanks a lot for your edit!

Comment: Difficult to analyse without the style. Does it works (beside the code color) if you use `\duck[stripes={\stripes[color=blue]}]`?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. In case it helps, the v0.4 `.sty` file can be found at https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks.sty

Comment: There is a brace missing around #1 in the alias definition. I edited the answer.

Comment: Fantastic - everything works now! Thank you very much for all your time and effort! Bounty and a donkey duck will arrive in 8 hours (or would you prefer some other duck?)

Comment: Hm. I could ask @DavidCarlisle if he has a good suggestion ;-).

Comment: The promised donkey duck: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxR9f.png